# "object is not a function" error during MongoDB document insertion from a CSV stream using async.queue

Tags: node.js, mongodb, csv

I'm trying MongoDB document insertion from a CSV stream using async.queue.
But I face this following error. I've tried all the remedies given in similar SO posts.

Exact error message is:

> C:\Users\admin\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:406
>       throw err
>   TypeError:object is not a function
>    at C:\Users\admin\Desktop\mynodefile.js:13:2
>   at C:\Users\admin\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:403:11
>   at process._tickCallback(node.js:355:11)

node.js code I used:

```
var csv = require('csv');
var async = require('async');
var fs = require('fs');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017', function(err, db) {
if (err) throw err;

var collection = db.collection('myCSVs');
var queue = async.queue(collection.insert.bind(collection), 5);

csv()
.from.path('./input.csv', { columns: true })
.transform(function (data, index, cb) {
    queue.push(data, function (err, res) {
        if (err) return cb(err);
        cb(null, res[0]);
    });
})
.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log('ERROR: ' + err.message);
})
.on('end', function () {
    queue.drain = function() {
        collection.count(function(err, count) {
            console.log('Number of documents:', count);
            db.close();
        });
    };
});
});
```

Comment: seems the 'csv().from' cause the error, remove the '()' from csv..

Comment: @xwhyLikeThis.Thanks. I've tried removing '()'.Now a different error pops up.Cannot read property 'path' of undefined
   at C:\Users\admin\Desktop\mynodefile.js:14:7
   at C:\Users\admin\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:403:11
   at process._tickCallback(node.js:355:11)

Comment: 13:2 is which line in your program??

Comment: @Subburaj.13:2 is the csv() line.

Comment: Are you sure `res[0]` exists? The documentation for [`async.queue()`](https://github.com/caolan/async#queueworker-concurrency) doesn't seem to suggest that the callback to `.push()` gets a second argument at all.

Comment: @nalin The error message changed because the problem is fixed. The new error is meant for another problem. The new error is caused because the csv.from is undefined. So what you need to check is how to correctly get the from or whatever property you want from the csv object. You can look for the library's documentation or looking into the source code of it or you just console.log(csv) to see what is inside....

Comment: @xwhyLikeThis Actually I did look into its usage. Its correct usage includes '()' .please have a look at http://csv.adaltas.com/legacy/

Comment: guys I just tried this:   
    var csv = require('csv');
    csv()
   .from('./input_csv_file.csv')
   .on('end', function(){ console.log('done'); })
Even this causes the "object is not a function" error.

Comment: hi, after some searching, I think the code is fine, but the csv version you have installed is the latest version, which violates all the sample codes in github, the latest version of the lib make csv an Object instead of a function. Maybe you need to specify the csv version in the dependencies. Check your package.json and see what is the version for csv, you should use version 0.3.7 I think.

Comment: @xwhyLikeThis Thank you!! It helped. I reinstalled csv using "npm install csv@0.3.7".Finally it made the error go away.If you submit this as an answer I will definitely vote for it(If voting is the right term..I'm new to SO).

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned the database name in your `MongoClient.connect` function call. You can do so like this:

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/database_name',function(err, db) {
```

Then you can do:

```
var collection = db.collection('myCSVs');
```

If myCSVs is a collection inside database_name

Or you can also do:

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017',function(err, mongoclient) {
    var db = mongoclient.db('database_name');
    var collection = db.collection('myCSVs');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort.Tried your answer but adding db name did not do any good.The error persists!!

Comment: is `myCSVs` the name of a collection inside a db? What's the db name?

Comment: db name is "db" and yes "myCSVs" is a collection inside it

Comment: Well, you have to mention the database name, otherwise `db.collection` won't be recognized as a valid method. Replace the `database_name` in my code above to `db` if you haven't already done so. That should fix the error. I'm out of ideas if that doesn't.

Comment: I've tried ur both methods. Didn't help. Anyway thanks.Actually I think there is no problem connecting to the database as I am able to successfully insert some data as a test.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change

```
var queue = async.queue(collection.insert.bind(collection), 5);
```

Into:

```
var q = async.queue(function (task, callback) {
    console.log('hello ' + task.name);
    callback();
}, 2);
```

IN this line :

```
queue.push(data, function (err, res) {
        if (err) return cb(err);
        cb(null, res[0]);
    });
```

you are calling push with data and with a callback, but its not implemented in your

```
var queue = async.queue(collection.insert.bind(collection), 5);
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried your answer. Again to my greatest misfortune the error is not resolved!